# How to run an algorithm multiple times and store the results in a matrix in R?

Tags: r, algorithm

Suppose I am running the following loop (trying to acheive convergence for y)

```
j=1
maxiter=10

for (j<maxiter) {

y[j]=y[j-1]+1  (#just to take an e.g of newton raphson method)

j=j+1
```

}

I want to run this loop 500 times and put the resulting values of y in a matrix. More specifically if I am running an algorithm and I want to run the algorithm 500 times, How do I do it?

Comment: do you mean you want to obtain a matrix of dimensions 500 * `maxiter` as a final result? if so, you shouldn't be overwriting `y` but keeping the values. also have a vector of length 500 of intitial `y` values.

Comment: beware in R index begins at 1 per default...

Comment: It's not clear to me what that loop/function is supposed to do, but `sapply()` run over some vector (e.g., the integers 1 to 500) will return a vector of equivalent length with the results of your function applied to that vector. E.g., `sapply(seq(500), function(x) x + 10)` will return 11, 12,...509, 510. It seems like that's where you're headed.

Comment: `sapply` is unlikely to be useful for recursive/sequential iteration. use `Reduce` with `accumulate=TRUE`.

Comment: `sapply` will do the job as it will be over a dummy variable (number of experiments): recursive iteration will be happening inside

Comment: actually function `replicate` does exactly what was suggested above (wraps around sapply see: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you appear to be mixing up 'for loops' and 'while loops'.
A 'for loop' is used by giving the set of values to use, e.g. for(i in 1:10) would run 10 times changing the value of i progressively from 1 to 10 each loop.
A 'while loop' will run infinitely as long as its condition is met,e.g.
`i=1
while(i<10) i=i+1`
That would run 9 times resulting in i==10.

There may be more efficient ways to accomplish your goal as indicated in the comments above but to keep in line with your original code you need something like this:

```
j=1  
y=1 # Whatever starting value you think appropriate for your convergence.
while(j<500) y[j+1]=y[j]+1
```

This will create a vector of values (though non-converging in this case).

Comment: well it is difficult to share my original code because it is an em algorithm and no one in this forum would ever want to go thru it given my previous experience. wat i basically want is em algorithm should be run 500 times and give me converged values in some form. i tried all means as told above bt its not giving me results.